# Difference between Ad-hoc polymorphism and Parametric polymorphism in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming, polymorphism, parametric-polymorphism, adhoc-polymorphism

So, I have been searching documentation about the main difference between  `parametric polymorphism` and `adhoc-polymorphism`, but I still have some doubts.

For instance, methods like `head` in Collections, are clearly parametric polymorphism, since the code used to obtain the head in a List[Int] is the same as in any other List.

```
List[T] {
    def head: T = this match {
        case x :: xs => x
        case Nil => throw new RuntimeException("Head of empty List.") 
    }
}
```

(Not sure if that's the actual implementation of head, but it doesn't matter)

On the other hand, type classes are considered adhoc-polymorphism. Since we can provide different implementations, bounded to the types.

```
trait Expression[T] {
    def evaluate(expr: T): Int
}

object ExpressionEvaluator {
  def evaluate[T: Expression](value: T): Int = implicitly[Expression[T]].evaluate(value)
}

implicit val intExpression: Expression[Int] = new Expression[Int] {
  override def evaluate(expr: Int): Int = expr
}

ExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(5)
// 5
```

In the middle, we have methods like filter, that are parametrized, but we can provide different implementations, by providing different functions.

```
List(1,2,3).filter(_ % 2 == 0)
// List(2)
```

Are methods like filter, map, etc, considered ad-hoc polymorphism? Why or why not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method `filter` on `List`s is an example of parametric polymorphism. The signature is

```
def filter(p: (A) ⇒ Boolean): List[A]
```

It works in exactly the same way for all types `A`. Since it can be *parameterized* by any type `A`, it's ordinary *parametric* polymorphism.

Methods like `map` make use of both types of polymorphism simultaneously.

Full signature of `map` is:

```
final def map[B, That]
  (f: (A) ⇒ B)
  (implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[List[A], B, That])
: That
```

This method relies on the presence of an implicit value (the CBF-gizmo), therefore it's ad-hoc polymorphism. However, some of the implicit methods that provide the CBFs of the right type are actually themselves parametrically polymorphic in types `A` and `B`. Therefore, unless the compiler manages to find some very special ad-hoc construct like an `CanBuildFrom[List[String], Int, BitSet]` in the implicit scope, it will sooner or later fall back to something like

```
implicit def ahComeOnGiveUpAndJustBuildAList[A, B]
: CanBuildFrom[List[A], B, List[B]]
```

Therefore, I think one could say that it's a kind-of "hybrid parametric-ad-hoc polymorphism" that first attempts to find the most appropriate ad-hoc type class `CanBuildFrom[List[A], B, That]` in the implicit scope, but eventually falls back to ordinary parametric polymorphism, and returns a one-fits-all `CanBuildFrom[List[A], B, List[B]]`-solution that is parametrically polymorphic in both `A` and `B`.